# C: Deallocating dynamicly created memory stored in a staticly created array

Tags: arrays, c, memory, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

Consider that I have a static array of custom structs called 'Books' `Book table[10];` that I will use as an easy way of keeping tack of all of my Books.

I plan to fill this array with structs that I create by calling malloc like so: `Book *new_book = (Book*) malloc(sizeof(Book));` and then assigning them to the array: `table[0] = *new_book;`

Do I need to still free() the new_book that I created? Typically the saying goes that for every malloc() there should be another free() but I'm a little confused about this situation as the data stored in the array is stack based and not heap based.

If I should be freeing the memory, what would a "proper" way be of freeing() it as the memory address for the original creation would be lost as I reference it via the array now instead.

Comment: Yes it needs to be freed. You are making *a copy* of the original dynamic struct and storing it into the array. So the dynamic memory still need to be freed. You can free it as soon as it has been copied into the array. Better still, instead of copying, define the array to store pointers instead of the full struct. That way you can store the dynamic memory pointer into the array and then free the pointer when the array (or individual elements) are no longer needed.

Comment: @kaylum explained the details well. As a rule of thumb, every time you call `malloc` you need to eventually call `free`. You are dynamically allocating memory on the heap when `malloc` is called, even if the data stored in dynamic memory comes from another memory segment.

Comment: Is there _one_ question or a door opened? I see "_Do I need to still free() the new_book that I created?_" - is that it?

Comment: I think the OP confusion is right here: `table[0] = *new_book;`. This doesn't copy a reference or address, it's a copy of memory contents from the region you allocated with `malloc` to the other region referenced by the array (automatically allocated onto the stack when the array was created).

Comment: @kaylum nailed it on the head and answered pretty much everything I wanted. If you repost it as a reply I'll mark it as an answer. You and Jardel were right in that my confusion stemmed from the fact that it is copying the contents and not a reference! Thanks all for the help.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `malloc` at all.  You *already* have storage for the struct.  Just use it in-place.  You can even assign `new_book = &table[i];` if you want to access it through a structure pointer (which you would *not* have to free in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it still needs to be freed. More details with correct answers are already in the comments from @kaylum and @Jardel Lucca.